# HoughLines returns 3-value vectors

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running `cv2.HoughLines()` and I thought it returns a list of list containing just rho and theta. however, what I get is a list of list containing 3 values. Does anyone know why? Here's my output:

```
[[ 274.            2.11184835  563.        ]]
[[  -8.            2.30383468  500.        ]]
[[ 219.            2.14675498  479.        ]]
[[ 142.           2.1991148  460.       ]]
...
```

I'm on 3.4.

EDIT: Here's some code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys
import math

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)

    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        fn = "../data/pic1.png"

    src = cv.imread(fn)
    dst = cv.Canny(src, 50, 200)
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(dst, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    if False: # HoughLinesP
        lines = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, math.pi/180.0, 40, np.array([]), 50, 10)
        a,b,c = lines.shape
        for i in range(a):
            cv.line(cdst, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)

    else:    # HoughLines
        lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, math.pi/180.0, 50, np.array([]), 0, 0)
        if lines is not None:
            a,b,c = lines.shape
            for i in range(a):
                print(lines[i])
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I've added some code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your script, I am getting two values only. This is my output.

```
[[ 274.            2.11184835]]
[[-8.          2.30383468]]
[[ 219.            2.14675498]]
```

Check your output once again. Else you can change your code much simpler like this:

```
lines = cv.HoughLines(dst, 1, math.pi/180.0, 50, np.array([]), 0, 0)
for i in range(len(lines)):
   for rho,theta in lines[i]:
       print(rho,theta)
```

Comment: I've just recompiled and it seems to return 2 values now. Not sure what was going on.